# why is boolean type in C written as _Bool?

Tags: c, boolean, standards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between _Bool and bool types in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724349/difference-between-bool-and-bool-types-in-c)

I just don't get it.
For me, it seems quite unintuitive - compared to simple "bool" :)

What were the motives to call it that way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724349/difference-between-bool-and-bool-types-in-c

Comment: I'm guessing it's because it's not a standard type. What platform? EDIT: never mind, see above.

Comment: creating a new keyword `bool` could make very many existing programs break; on the other hand, programs that used `_Bool` were messing in implementation workspace and it is more probable that there aren't that many of those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Identifiers which begin with one or two underscores are reserved for the language and compiler.

I expect that they didn't want to break existing ('legacy') code, which might have used 'bool' as the name of a variable.

Comment: so they thought they would (potentionally) break less legacy code defining a keyword "_Bool" than defining "bool" ?

Comment: Exactly, since legacy code was expressly prohibited from using "_Bool" while expressly permitted to use "bool".

Comment: @Novellizator Yes, because legacy code wan't allowed to be using "_Bool" in the first place: because any identifier that starts with an underscore is reserved.