# Can you use scanf to test a valid input for _Bool type? Regarding C

Tags: c, boolean, scanf

I have a question about this fragment of code I wrote in C:

```
 printf("Do you own a microwave?Enter 1 for Yes and 0 for No\n");
    while((scanf("%d",&microw))==0){
        printf("Please enter a valid number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&microw);}
```

My compiler says the following: "format `%d` expects argument of type `int*` but argument 2 has type `_Bool*`". As far as I am informed, boolean was considered an int type so I am not sure why this warning is received. How else would I be able to test for this condition other than to set up another variable to test with `scanf`, and then assigning another variable of `_Bool` type to true or false? Any feedback is appreciated. I thank you all :).

Comment: Are you using `_Bool` or `_bool`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724349/difference-between-bool-and-bool-types-in-c for more info on Boolean types in C

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving it because, well, it's expecting an `int *` and you're passing a `_Bool *`. They're both integers, but different types - on my system `_Bool` has a size of 1, and `int` a size of 4.

There's no `scanf` specifier for what you want, so you'll need to use a `char` if you really want the minimum storage. You can always assign the value to a `_Bool` afterwards.

e.g.

```
scanf("%c",&microw);
_Bool b = microw - '0';
```

(Also, your code won't work as you intend. If you enter an invalid character with `%d`, it'll go into an endless loop.)

Comment: I was hoping for a specifier because otherwise, there is more hassle involved in assigning the _Bool values themselves. But no worries. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it :)!