# Cesar Cipher out of bounds in Array

Tags: c

Guys i found this caesar cipher code in some site.... But when i run it its showing segmentation fault in online compilers..but in c compiler tat i'm using its showing processor fault... can anyone pls point out the wrong in this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define caesar(x) rot(13, x)
#define decaesar(x) rot(13, x)
#define decrypt_rot(x, y) rot((26-x), y) 

void rot(int c, char *str)
{
    int l = strlen(str);
    const char *alpha[2] = { "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(str[i]))
            continue;

        str[i] = alpha[isupper(str[i])][((int)(tolower(str[i])-'a')+c)%26];
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "This is a top secret text message!";

    printf("Original: %s\n", str);
    caesar(str);
    printf("Encrypted: %s\n", str);
    decaesar(str);
    printf("Decrypted: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **1.** Please change your title. **2.** Did you try to debug it? You're probably getting out of bounds in `alpha`.

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to use the debugger [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). Running your program in a debugger will make it stop when and where the crash happens, and let you examine the call stack and the variables.

Comment: and i have used <ctype.h> also...but still im getting those errors..

Comment: ...and indent your code properly

Comment: That cast to int is redundant.

Comment: No its not the problem...the prob is only in array declaration...when i erase the uppercase alphabets and run it...i get the output...but when i have those i couldnt get it..

Comment: What is your compiler? do you get 1 or 0 with isupper()? And don't you get -1 by printf("%d\n", !0);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct except for one detail, which might be confusing for a newbie.

It is ok to assume that the function `isupper()` returns a boolean value 1 or 0, but if you check the documentation it says *A value different from zero (i.e., true) if indeed c is an uppercase alphabetic letter. Zero (i.e., false) otherwise.*
This and the fact that `isupper()` is returning an int and not a _Bool is causing the problem.

`int isupper ( int c );`

When returning true `isupper()` might return any non_zero value. In my case it returns `8` ( a specific bit-field ). Probably the same in yours.

All you have to do is cast the return of `isupper()` to `_Bool`

```
printf("%d   %d" ,(_Bool)isupper('A') , ((int)(tolower(str[i])-'a')+c)%26 ) ;
```

Comment: what's the difference between `bool` and `_Bool` ?

Comment: @DanFromGermany http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724349/difference-between-bool-and-bool-types-in-c

Comment: I got it.. But i can't get the output in compiler that im using..its showing undefined symbol (_Bool).....could u pls refer me someother complier..and download link for that too :)

Comment: @SharathKumar `#include <stdbool.h>` http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/stdbool.h.html

Comment: @Armin i did that too...its saying couldn't open the file

Comment: @SharathKumar Just replace `(_Bool)` with `!!`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely your use of `isupper` as index. It's not guaranteed to return `1` for true values, just that it will return "true" (which may be any non-zero value).

You can solve this by using the ternary expression:

```
alpha[isupper(str[i]) ? 1 : 0][...]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration of your loop, you are trying to write to `alpha[256][6]`, (`isupper` does not always return `0` or `1`)

> isupper returns: A value different from zero (i.e., true) if indeed c is an
>   uppercase alphabetic letter. Zero (i.e., false) otherwise.

`alpha[isupper(str[i]) != 0][...]` will do the trick

Also note that you should always cast the argument you pass to
isupper(), isalnum(), etc. to unsigned char