# function with bool return type in OpenGL ES shader using GPUImage

Tags: ios, opengl-es, boolean, gpuimage, fragment-shader

I'm working on an iOS project, using GPUImage framework. I cannot get my shader complied.

---

There's a function in my fragment shader:

```
const vec2 boundMin = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
const vec2 boundMax = vec2(1.0, 1.0);

bool inBounds (vec2 p) {
   return all(lessThan(boundMin, p)) && all(lessThan(p, boundMax));
}
```

Shader compile log:

```
ERROR: 0:1: '_Bool' : syntax error syntax error
```

---

When I replace all the calls to function

`inBounds(vec2 p)`

with

`all(lessThan(boundMin, p)) && all(lessThan(p, boundMax))`

it works **great!**

---

Questions:

Is bool function supported in OpenGL ES 2.0 Fragment Shader? If so, where did I go wrong? If not, why there're functions like `all()`, `lessThan()`, etc.

Environment: iPad mini, iOS 7, OpenGL ES 2.0, Xcode 5.0.2

Comment: Can you show the entire shader? If I am reading that compile log correctly, it is complaining about the first line.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I don't think it's the first line, because when I delete the `inBounds` function, it works fine. I believe it's the function itself that causes the problem. Do you use GPUImage? I don't think GPUImage's shader compile log can give the exact location of an error.

Comment: 0:1 usually means something to the effect of the first character on line 1. Each vendor is different, but that tends to be the convention.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman my first line is `precision highp float;` ...

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman iOS does support `highp`, I know that, and I'm using `highp` in other fragment shaders, it's fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figure it out!

GPUImage uses SHADER_STRING() to parse shaders.

When I write `bool`, the LLVM Objective-C compiler did not know this pice of code will be converted to shader string. When the compiler sees `bool` it will replace `bool` with `_Bool`, because in Objective-C `bool` is defined to be `_Bool`!

Comment: It's not just Objective-C, it's C99 that uses a compiler macro for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8724376/19679 . My use of macros rather than strings for the fragment shaders (to avoid newlines and allow for some syntax highlighting) opens them up to this. There might be side-effects, but you could try `#undefine bool` right before your shader definition. I'll note this in the documentation.