# What does b = a && b mean in C?

Tags: c, logic, logical-operators

```
a=5; b=0; c=1;
if(b=2) c = a++ & b;
else a=4;
b = a && b;
```

Code is in C. How will this code work? What will a, b, c have values? What 
does `b = a && b` mean in C?

Comment: It would be somewhere in the first two chapters of any decent C book.

Comment: the value of `a && b` is equal to `0` or `1`

Comment: this code has syntax errors too

Comment: Such as `if(b=2)`

Comment: Not a syntax error, strictly speaking. But a funny thing, which can make OPs life interesting.

Comment: bwnuk, even with the simplest beginner code you should always use clean formatting. You are just making things harder on yourself by making a mess on the screen. Finally, just use a debugger and watch the values change as you walk the code. This is a skill you will always need.

Comment: @EugeneSh. :)))

Comment: *"What will a, b, c have values?"* The values you see if you take the trouble to print them. Basic debugging technique, without a debugger.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi what other syntax errors were you seeing?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was bad question. I have already debugged and I have one more question. Why is c equal to 0? I understand why b is equal to 1 and why a is equal to 6. But can't find clue with c.

Comment: Ok, I found a solution. Sorry for a stupid question. Thanks for motivation :)

Comment: @WeatherVane a , b , c has no type , assuming their type is `int` he uses `;` for separating them instead of `,` in one line , actually he uses 3 semi colons in one line

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi those are just 3 statements on one line. No syntax error, but poor formatting.

Comment: @WeatherVane yep , you are right , but very poor formatting ...

Answer (score 2):

In C, `&&` is the logical AND operator. Therefore `a && b` is the result of the logical operation "a AND b". Since C originally had no boolean type you often see `int` being "abused" as an substitute. An `int` is "true", if it has a non-zero value - and "false" if it is zero. (I think C99 added some boolean type called `_Bool`, but I'm not exactly sure on that one.) So the result of the expression `a && b` is either 1, if both a and b are non-zero, or zero if (at least) one of them is zero. That also is what gets assigned to b in `b = a && b;` then.

However, there also is the binary `&` operator in C, which is the [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) and does something different than `&&`. This can also be a source of confusion and unintended errors/bugs in C code, because accidentally missing a `&` in `&&` changes the behaviour of the compiled code.

Comment: FYI, the C99 keyword is `_Bool`, with an optional typedef of `bool`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724349/difference-between-bool-and-bool-types-in-c for details

Comment: @Zrax: Thanks, I've changed it in my answer.